# Set up SQL Database accessed by Java, without Server needs (Embedded?)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, derby, javadb

I am currently working on a university project to set up a database and a java GUI for the company I work at.

My idea was to use JavaDB (JDK-integrated Derby) or MySQL as database engine and connect to a Java application that I code using DBMC.

Ideally, both the Database and GUI Java Application would simply be saved on the company's network drive in the same folder, without the need of a permanently running an SQL server or something like that. 
So when a user started up the Java application, the database (server) would start up too and close when the Java Application is closed.

I was messing around with Derby Embedded, but found that it was fairly impractical, lacking a useful gui administration tool like MySQL or multi-user access (not the first priority) and accessing it via SQuirreL didn't succeed very well either.

Do you know a better solution to this? 
Would it be possible to do this with MySQL for example?

I hope, I explained everything okay.

Comment: Make a decision. Either you want a single-app database that starts and stops with the app, or you want a multi-app database that's always running, ready to serve the multiple apps. For single-app, embedded is good. For multi-app, you need a database server that's always running.

Comment: I've used Squirrel with Derby for years, it works great.

Comment: What I basically need is a simple solution that stores the database on our network directory which can be accessed from any desktop pc using the java application.
This is because I am sure the IT department would not set up a whole SQL Server just for this project.

Is Derby Embedded the only solution to this? What if I would like to use MySQL this way? 
Or am I just misunterstanding the whole 'server' thing and it is way easier than I think?